# Cannot run the command react-native link

Tags: javascript, react-native, command-line, native, react-native-cli

I'm kinda of stuck.
I'm trying to run the command :

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

And when I send the command I getting this erro :

[image]

Please help , I need this for solve other issue and no matter what I do i cannot solve it

This is the info for react

[image]

Comment: did you try running the command using npx? it is recommend you access the current version at runtime using npx.

Comment: If you are using react-native version > 0.6 you don't need to link, it is auto-linked.